# How to allow error on Android Fragment?

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-fragments, android-listview

I have an error in my code, why could happen?
error occurred on :

- setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menuangkot);
- String[] array_angkot = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_angkot);
- listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_angkot);
- editSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editSearch);
- adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_angkot,
  R.id.text_nama, array_angkot);

Her error is The method setContentView(int) is undefined for the type HomeFragment, The constructor ArrayAdapter(HomeFragment, int, int, String[]) is undefined

Please help Me ...

### HomeFragment.java

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

private ListView listView;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private EditText editSearch;

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listNama;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // dapatkan data string array dari XML
    String[] array_angkot = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_angkot);

    // deklarasi object listview & edittext dengan layout xml
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_angkot);
    editSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editSearch);

    // instansiasi arrayadapter dengan parameter (context,resource,textview
    // resource,array string)
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_angkot,
            R.id.text_nama, array_angkot);
```

Comment: Use google to find out how fragment should be created. Fragment is not Activity!

Comment: So what should I change ?? please help, my difficulty with it @skywall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `setContentView` is used for `Activity`-derived classes. When you are developing a `Fragment`, you never call `setContentView` (as the error message says, that method is undefined in a `Fragment`). Instead, you override `onCreateView` and return the root of the view hierarchy that will be used for that `Fragment`. As @skywall suggests, you should read the documentation for how to create a `Fragment` (including how to add it to an `Activity`). The place to start is the [Guide topic on `Fragments`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). You should also consult the [documentation for the `Fragment` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html), which includes a description of the `Fragment` lifecycle and the methods you may need to override.

Then you need to reorganize your code so that the process of setting up the view that you now have in `onCreate` occurs instead in `onCreateView`.